# how to add multiple system sha-keys in google single sign on gson?

Tags: android, google-signin

I am integrating google sign on in android app. When I generated google-services.gson I have given my PC sha-key, If I generate apk using my system, it is working, but If I generate same APK in another system, It is giving google error. How to add multiple system sha-keys for google sign on. I don't know where to add exactly and developer console and how to add multiple sha-keys in google-services.gson

Thank you!

Comment: Does this help? http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2016/03/registering-oauth-clients-for-google.html

Comment: Yes thank you @StevenSoneff

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As StevenSoneff replied, you can add any number of sha keys of your team by following below blog

http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2016/03/registering-oauth-clients-for-google.html